# Help, VSC me coloca el cursor automáticamente

Tags: vscode, formato

no se que he tocado pero VSC atuomaticamtne me coloca el cursor al final del ultimo caracter, si le das enter baja y sube automáticamente y además justifica el nexo por si solo.

Alguien me puede ayudar a rehabilitarlo porque es tedioso, tardo más tiempo en posicionar el texto que en escribir.

Estoy pensando en desinstalarlo porque me tiene loco

Comment: alguna extension se rompio?

Comment: llevo poco programando y con vsc procuro tocar lo menos posible

Comment: y tenes alguna extension que se pudo haber roto?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.